# Is there a template or feat that grants Air Walk as a spell-like or supernatural ability?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-templates

Is there a template (whether legal or not, and regardless of level adjustment) or feat which grants Air Walk as a Spell-like or Supernatural ability? Preferably at will. Any books including 3rd party, *Dungeon* magazine and *Dragon* magazine are allowed in my group.

The only ones I can find that grant it at all are half air elemental templates, and those are only 1 time per day.

Comment: Also, how important is *air walk* specifically? If the template doesn’t need to explicitly reference that specific spell by name, what attributes of *air walk* must be retained? Templates that grant unlimited flight are quite common, of course, so I assume that’s not good enough, but explaining what flight is missing for your purposes would help a great deal.

Comment: When you say legally, are you referring to one of those professional play groups? It's just for a home game. No max amount of LA but the lower, the better. Air Walk is the entire reason for the question so it's pretty important. I'm not interested in normal flight at all in regards to this. I want to combine Air Walk with the Footsteps of the Mage feat to create an absolutely unique form of flight. Different from what everyone else does.

Comment: If you've ever seen the movie Dark City, the Strangers had a version of flying I'd never seen before and never seen since. I figured out that combining those two things will accurately simulate it for D&D. I'm just having trouble locating a way to get Air Walk at will

Comment: When I say “legally,” I mean the rules let you. Players are not usually allowed to use a template without an LA (or equivalently with LA —). Anyway, please include these details in your question it will help people help you.

Comment: @KRyan ok fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Scorn Earth* (Su) class feature of the Elocater prestige class (Expanded Psionics Handbook; pages 142-144) allows one to float, hover, walk, run, and fight normally... one foot above the ground (flat surface part of solid or liquid). It also allows one to move at a speed of 10' per round at elevations higher than that. There does not appear to be any upper limit on height, nor limit on duration. There is a penalty to combat when so elevated, however.

Other than the speed and the combat penalty, this is possibly superior to *Air Walk* in other respects. One might want to consider faster methods of elevation, and then sauntering around with this ability once you get up there.

---

Great for those floating meditating mystic old being mentor types, or wuxia stand-on-a-branch warriors, or impressively stand in mid air to look down on others characters.

Comment: WOW! You aren't kidding! Not only does this seem superior to Air Walk, but with its wording I wouldn't even need Footsteps of the Mage to get the effect I want! Thanks, this is perfect.

Comment: "Instead of walking she glides along, unconcerned with the hard earth or difficult terrain. While she remains within 1 foot of a flat surface of any solid or liquid" That does seem to contradict itself.